# TA-LIB module has no attribute 'add_all_ta_features'

Tags: python, ta-lib

I'm trying to use TA-lib for a hobby project. I found some code-snippets as reference telling me to do the following;

```
import talib as ta
ta.add_all_ta_features("some parameters here")
```

i get the following error when running the code:

`ta.add_all_ta_features( AttributeError: module 'talib' has no attribute 'add_all_ta_features'`

It looks like i need to manualy add all the features i want as i cant find the attribute .add_all_ta_features in the talib folder.

i've installed TA-Lib and made it a 64-bit library using Visual studio and managed to run TA-Lib in other projects before but have never used the .add_all_ta_features-attribute.

Does anybody know how i can fix this? Google seems to not return any usefull results when searched for this. The documentation i'm following also does not mention anything about this attribute.

i tried using pandas_ta and tried using the Google colab space, but both return the same error.

Comment: afaik, there is no any `add_all_ta_features`

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I was trying to use TA-Lib as TA, but nowhere was it specified that we need a seperate library, not findable through the python package mangager simply called TA.

Thanks!